# Fast sequential addition to rectangular subarray in numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have come across a problem which is to rewrite a piece of code in vectorized form. The code shown below is a simplified illustration of initial problem

```
K = 20
h, w = 15, 20 
H, W = 1000-h, 2000-w 
q = np.random.randint(0, 20, size=(H, W, K))  # random just for illustration 
Q = np.zeros((H+h, W+w, K))
for n in range(H):
    for m in range(W):
        Q[n:n+h, m:m+w, :] += q[n, m, :]
```

This code takes long to execute and it seems to me it is rather simple to allow vectorized implementation.

I am aware of  numpy's  [`s_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html) function which allows to construct slices which in turn can help in code vectorizing. But because every single element in `Q` is the result of multiple subsequent additions of elements from `q` I found it difficult  to proceed in that simple way.

I guess  that [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) could be useful to cope with sequential addition. But i have spent much time trying to make this two functions work for me and decided to ask for help because I constantly get an

```
IndexError: failed to coerce slice entry of type numpy.ndarray to integer
```

for any attempt i make.

Maybe there is some another numpy's magic which I am unaware of and which could help me in my task but it seems extremely difficult to google for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you are basically summing across sliding windows along the first and second axes, which in signal processing domain is termed as [`convolution`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). For two axes that would be `2D convolution`. Now, Scipy has it implemented as [`convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) and could be used for each slice along the third axis.

Thus, we would have an implementation with it, like so -

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

kernel = np.ones((h,w),dtype=int)
m,n,r = q.shape[0]+h-1, q.shape[1]+w-1, q.shape[2]
out = np.empty((m,n,r),dtype=q.dtype)
for i in range(r):
    out[...,i] = convolve2d(q[...,i],kernel)
```

As it turns out, we can use [`fftconvolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html) from the same repo that allows us to work with higher-dimensional arrays. This would get us the output in a fully vectorized way, like so -

```
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve

out = fftconvolve(q,np.ones((h,w,1),dtype=int))
```

**Runtime test**

Function definitions -

```
def original_app(q,K,h,w,H,W):
    Q = np.zeros((H+h-1, W+w-1, K))
    for n in range(H):
        for m in range(W):
            Q[n:n+h, m:m+w, :] += q[n, m, :]
    return Q        

def convolve2d_app(q,K,h,w,H,W):
    kernel = np.ones((h,w),dtype=int)
    m,n,r = q.shape[0]+h-1, q.shape[1]+w-1, q.shape[2]
    out = np.empty((m,n,r),dtype=q.dtype)
    for i in range(r):
        out[...,i] = convolve2d(q[...,i],kernel)
    return out

def fftconvolve_app(q,K,h,w,H,W):
    return fftconvolve(q,np.ones((h,w,1),dtype=int))
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [128]: # Setup inputs
     ...: K = 20
     ...: h, w = 15, 20 
     ...: H, W = 200-h, 400-w
     ...: q = np.random.randint(0, 20, size=(H, W, K))
     ...: 

In [129]: %timeit original_app(q,K,h,w,H,W)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.05 s per loop

In [130]: %timeit convolve2d_app(q,K,h,w,H,W)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.05 s per loop

In [131]: %timeit fftconvolve_app(q,K,h,w,H,W)
1 loops, best of 3: 233 ms per loop

In [132]: np.allclose(original_app(q,K,h,w,H,W),convolve2d_app(q,K,h,w,H,W))
Out[132]: True

In [133]: np.allclose(original_app(q,K,h,w,H,W),fftconvolve_app(q,K,h,w,H,W))
Out[133]: True
```

So, it seems `fftconvolve` based approach is doing really well there!

Comment: That is brilliant aswer, thanks a lot!  Btw, i guess `dtype=int` is not very meaningful because  `fftconvolve` converts it's arguments into float anyway.